# 59 days passed and Full and Final settlement

Tags: human-resources, employer-relations, india

I hate to write this but I really need your suggestions.

I joined a company in November 2019. Everything was going fine until in July 20th I received a phone call from HR that 20th July is my last working day and I need to resign myself and that to over the email while they are over the call.
I did it as they said as there were 8 to 10 people over the call.

They said me that my full and final settlement will be done in within 45 days.

I did quit and started my job hunt during the pandemic. Today is it 59 days passed and I have yet not received my final settlement.

I tried writing emails to support at the company and they just reply me with parrot lines like it is in process.. we are working on your request.

I tried calling HR and she speaks so sweetly and says I have already given clearance on 20th July itself.

I don't know what to do now. :(

I did not received my Pay in July because of resignation on 20th July. No pay in August.
Now it is around 60 days and yet no full and final settlement.

My new employer will pay me on 1 October for the new role. I have no money with me at the moment. I am just asking my previous company for what I am entitled and on top of that I am asking after 45 days. They promised me 45 days would be the deadline when I should get my full and final settlement.

The company has really uprooted my faith in humanity.

Day after tomorrow I am going to involve my parents in this but before that I want to talk to HR on Monday.

What should I say them?? I have already told them my problem and their commitment.

Comment: Can you please explain what "full and final settlement" means - is it specific to India's labour code? Also, why would you involve your parents in this - again, is it customary for India? And one last thing I didn't understand - did your employer provide any reasons for why they want you to resign effective today?

Comment: What do you have *in writing* from Cerner?

Comment: What do you have *in writing* from your previous employer?

Comment: It sounds like "full and final settlement" means your last paycheck, where you're given everything the company owes you. See for example https://m.economictimes.com/wealth/earn/soon-you-will-get-full-and-final-payment-just-2-days-after-you-leave-job/articleshow/72484328.cms

Comment: @Egor ,, Full and Final settlement means the last final check and the encasement of the holiday

Comment: So they asked you to resign and you did? Is this common in India?

Comment: still waiting..no response from them.

Comment: Nobody can force you to resign. What can they do? Fire you for not resigning?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with JW's answer, but I want to another point:

**Just before getting a lawyer, I would try sending one last email to the HR, saying that you will need to pursue legal action because this company X is withholding your legally earned pay.** This might have a positive effect and have funds wired to you quickly, because no sensible company (even the company you mentioned) does not want to deal with lawyers, legal stuff and bad publicity. This might save time, money and other things for both sides.

You can proceed with lawyer any time you want.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to convince someone who is saving money by not being convinced. There is no point in talking - let alone in undocumented talking.

Get legal support: Either a lawyer or some organization who can back you up.

Answer (score 3):

This is an advice specific to India

You can contact your labor officer and lodge a complaint. Labor officer has the power to summon you both to reach a settlement. This is just an intermediate step. You can also go to the police station and raise a complaint.

Involve a lawyer, if both is not working. You are entitled to receive the money you are owed.

Note: [Under new law, full and final settlement should be done in two days after last working day.](https://www.livemint.com/news/india/full-and-final-settlement-in-how-many-days-under-new-wage-code-11656644777238.html)